# Loops on a Matlab program

Tags: matlab

I have 3 sets of 10 vectors each, and I want to take 2 vectors from the first set , 2 vectors from the second set and 3 vectors from the third set . My goal is to make a loop to implement the following program, knowing that after each calculation, the result shall be saved in a new file.
My problem is that I can not handle the indices included in the strings. I try to use multiple loops to scan the 3 sets in the order of indices. loops should contain the following program

```
clc;  
clear all;  

load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_F.mat');  
load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_G.mat');  

F = m_F;  
G = m_G;  


load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_J.mat');  
load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_K.mat');  

J = m_J;  
K = m_K;  

load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_N.mat');  
load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_O.mat');  
load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_P.mat');    
N = m_N ;  
O = m_O;  
P = m_P;  

[A,B,C,D,E] = myFun(F,G,J,K,N,O,P);  

file_name = 'matrice_final.mat';  
save(file_name,'A','B','C','D','E');
```

I thank all those who responded to my question. Sorry if I was not as accurate from the outset. However, I would like the program looks something like:

```
clc; 


    clear all;    

    set1={F,G,FF,GG,X,Y,XX,L,BH,JK};  %set of name vectors  
    set2={J,K,HG,UY,TR,BC,XW,IOP,ES,QA};  %set of name vectors  
    set3={AJ,RK,DS,TU,WS,ZZE,ZXW,TYP,ZAA,QWW};  %set of name vectors  

for i=1:1:9    

        load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_'set1(i)'.mat');    
        load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_'set1(i+1)'.mat');   

        'set1(i)' = m_'set1(i)';     
        'set1(i+1)' = m_'set1(i+1)';     

    for j=1:1:9   

        load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_'set2(j)'.mat');     
        load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_'set2(j+1)'.mat');  

        'set2(j)' = m_'set2(j)';     
        'set2(j+1)' = m_'set2(j+1)';   

        for k=1:1:8   

            load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_'set3(k)'.mat');       
            load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_'set3(k+1)'.mat');      
            load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_'set3(k+2)'.mat');        

            'set3(k)' = m_'set3(k)' ;      
            'set3(k+1)' = m_'set3(k+1)';     
            'set3(k+2)' = m_'set3(k+2)';      

    [Result1'index',Result2'index',Result3'index',Result4'index',Result5'index'] = myFun('set1(i)','set1(i+1)','set2(j)','set2(j+1)','set3(k)','set3(k+1)','set3(k+2)');  %% 9x9x8=648   index=1,2,...,648      

    file_name = 'matrice_final'index'.mat';      
    save(file_name,'Result1'index'','Result2'index'','Result3'index'','Result4'index'','Result5'index'');        
        clear 'set3(k)' 'set3(k+1)' 'set3(k+2)'   
        end   
    clear 'set2(j)' 'set2(j+1)'   
    end   
    clear 'set1(i)' 'set1(i+1)'
end
```

Comment: What is your question?  You seem to just want us to give you code

Comment: loops is only to change the names of the vectors.I just want to know how to include the indices. Example, for   
 load ('C: \ Users \ Documents \ MATLAB \ myFile \ matrice_F.mat'); how i can change the matrice_F by matrice_H using a loop?

Comment: Still don't understand your question.  What do you mean by 'change the matrice_F'?

Comment: I have three sets of names of vectors, and I want to loop on these 3 sets in my program to change the vectors F, G, J, K, N, O, P. How I can do that? I can not handle the indices included in strings.

Comment: if set1={F,G,X,Y,Z,FF,GG,XX,YY,RR}, I want to replace matrice_F matrice_G by matrice_X and matrice_Y and so on ... the same thing for the other two sets

Comment: Hey lebland-matlab, I've posted a solution - I think that's what you want

Comment: Also do you want to automate the `[A,B,C,D,E] = myFun(F,G,J,K,N,O,P);  ` section ?

Comment: my goal is instead of changing the program every time to change the vectors, I make loops on the same program.

Comment: @Jacob: I have another problem now.it is the continuation of the above. I have a big job that I have to finish before Monday.

Comment: Yeah in my implementation you just have to change `matrices` string and it will load the matrices. Is there anything else you need to automate?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes the question

Answer (score 2):

*Note: Updated to meet the new requirements in the question...*

Here's a solution that avoids using [EVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html):

```
clc;
clear all;

set1 = {'F','G','FF','GG','X','Y','XX','L','BH','JK'};
set2 = {'J','K','HG','UY','TR','BC','XW','IOP','ES','QA'};
set3 = {'AJ','RK','DS','TU','WS','ZZE','ZXW','TYP','ZAA','QWW'};

matrices = cell(1,7);  %# An empty cell array
fileString = 'C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_';  %# First part of
                                                           %#   file name

for i = 1:9  %# Loop over set1

  fileData = load([fileString set1{i} '.mat']);  %# Load file
  matrices{1} = fileData.(['m_' set1{i}]);       %# Get matrix

  fileData = load([fileString set1{i+1)} '.mat']);  %# Load file
  matrices{2} = fileData.(['m_' set1{i+1}]);        %# Get matrix

  for j = 1:9  %# Loop over set2

    fileData = load([fileString set2{j} '.mat']);  %# Load file
    matrices{3} = fileData.(['m_' set2{j}]);       %# Get matrix

    fileData = load([fileString set2{j+1)} '.mat']);  %# Load file
    matrices{4} = fileData.(['m_' set2{j+1}]);        %# Get matrix

    for k = 1:8  %# Loop over set3

      fileData = load([fileString set3{k} '.mat']);  %# Load file
      matrices{5} = fileData.(['m_' set3{k}]);       %# Get matrix

      fileData = load([fileString set3{k+1} '.mat']);  %# Load file
      matrices{6} = fileData.(['m_' set3{k+1}]);       %# Get matrix

      fileData = load([fileString set3{k+2} '.mat']);  %# Load file
      matrices{7} = fileData.(['m_' set3{k+2}]);       %# Get matrix

      [A,B,C,D,E] = myFun(matrices{:});  %# Pass matrices to your function

      index = k+8*(j-1)+72*(i-1);        %# Combination index
      fileName = ['matrice_final' int2str(index) '.mat'];  %# Save file name
      save(fileName,'A','B','C','D','E');                  %# Save the data

    end
  end
end
```

I made one small modification. Instead of saving `A1` through `E1` in file `matrice_final1.mat`, and `A2` through `E2` in file `matrice_final2.mat`, etc., I just saved `A` through `E` in each file, since the file name itself already indicates the index. If you want to load multiple files at once without the matrices `A` through `E` overwriting each other, you can do the following:

```
data1 = load('matrice_final1.mat');  %# Load data into structure data1
data2 = load('matrice_final2.mat');  %# Load data into structure data2
```

Now, `data1.A` will give you `A` for index 1, and `data2.A` will give you `A` for index 2.

Comment: @Jacob: Sometimes I suppose EVAL is necessary, but I've never really liked it. Code using it never seems as clean or easy to read, and it's annoying having to escape `'` when you're working with strings in the expression to be evaluated. Often, there are better options to using EVAL, like using dynamic field names for structures (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html#br1v5cc-1) or cell arrays and comma-separated lists (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html).

Comment: True, I've never used `eval` before either - don't do much work which needs it.

Comment: @Jacob, @Pyrolistical : I thank all those who responded to my question. Sorry if I was not as accurate from the outset. However, I would like the program looks something as provided above.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

OK, so your program looks good, but you have some basic errors:

#### String concatenation:

```
load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_'set1(i)'.mat');
```

So the string you're passing to `load` isn't really a string until you concatenate it. For e.g.,
`['Hello' ' ' 'World']` will be the string `Hello World`. You need to enclose it in `[` and `]`.

So change the `load` statements to:

```
load(['C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_' set1(i) '.mat']);
```

#### Wrong use of `eval`

For `eval` to work, you need to construct the string (which is the command) and pass it to `eval`. The following will not work:

```
'set1(i)' = m_'set1(i)';
```

But this will work:

```
eval([ set1(i) ' = m_' set1(i) ';']);
```

Since it's the equivalent of (if `i = 1`);

```
A = m_A;
```

#### Use of `index`

I didn't understand the role of the `index` variable.

#### `clear`

`clear` can be used with string argument so:

```
clear 'set2(j)' 'set2(j+1)'
```

Should be changed to:

```
clear(set2(j),set2(j+1));
```

**Old Answer:**
You need [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html). I think it's not recommended but it seems to be the way to go for you.

```
%%// Cleanup
clc;  
clear all;  

%%// The loop
matrices = 'FGJKNOP';
for i = 1:numel(matrices)
    load_string = ['load(''C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_' matrices(i) '.mat'');'];
    eval(load_string); %// Example: load('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\myFile\matrice_F.mat'); 
    eval([matrices(i) ' = m_' matrices(i) ';']); %// Example: F = m_F;  

end

%%// Saving the data
results = 'ABCDE';
%// Make the string [A,B,C,D,E]
results_string = sprintf('%c,',results);
results_string = ['[' results_string(1:end-1) ']'];
%// Make the string (F,G,J,K,N,O,P)
matrices_args = sprintf('%c,',matrices);
matrices_args = ['(' matrices_args(1:end-1) ');'];    
%// Make the string ,'A','B','C','D','E' etc.
results_args = sprintf(',''%c''',results);

%// Save the data
eval([results_string ' = myFun' matrices_args]);
file_name = 'matrice_final.mat';
eval(['save(file_name' results_args ');']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I get it now.  You have having problems referring to the matrix loading from a mat file.  You know the name of the matrix from the .mat file, but how do you refer to it in matlab?

You need to use `eval`

You'll need to do something like:

1. Read the letter in the file name and store it in the variable `letter`
2. Load the matrix
3. Call `loaded_array = eval(['m_', letter])`;